# Standard install of VSExpress2012 on Win8, the IDE will not launch

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I have a windows 8 x64 machine, pretty new image, and I just installed VS2012 C# express, and the install completed fine.  but when I launch the IDE, nothing happens, I do not see a new process starting in Task Manager either.

After googling a bit, people suggest that it may be extensions and to run "devenv.exe /safemode".  I did not install any extensions, and "devenv.exe" does not exist in my system.  all I can find is %SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe.  This is where the shortcut created on my desktop points too.  I have tried using the " /safemode" switch with that .exe, but nothing happens.

I am currently running a repair on the program now, maybe that will fix it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, The Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit 5.6 was locking some files.  After removing it. VS2012 opened right up.